# Cookie monster problem: minimum moves to reduce all array elements to 0

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I am looking at the [cookie monster problem](https://www.transtutors.com/questions/def-food-piles-the-beloved-sesame-street-character-cookie-monster-has-stumbled-upon--7401545.htm):

> The Cookie Monster has a table with piles of cookies, each pile a positive integer. The Cookie Monster must eat these cookies in the shortest possible sequence of moves. Each move consists of the Cookie Monster choosing an integer  that must be one of the remaining pile sizes. The chosen move removes  cookies from every pile that contains at least  cookies, and leaves all the smaller piles as they were before the move.
>
> This function should compute and return the smallest number of moves that allows Cookie Monster to eat these cookies.
>
> | piles | Expected result | (optimal moves) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] | 3 | [4, 2, 1] |
> | [2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89] | 5 | [55, 21, 8, 3, 2] |
> | [1, 10, 17, 34, 43, 46] | 5 | [34, 9, 8, 3, 1] |
> | [11, 26, 37, 44, 49, 52, 68, 75, 87, 102] | 6 | [37, 31, 15, 12, 7, 4] |
> | `[2**n for n in range (10)]` | 10 | [512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1] |

I got this hint:

> For the given piles, your function should loop trough its possible moves, and recursively solve the problem for the new piles that result from applying each move to piles. The optimal solution for piles is then simply the optimal one of those subproblem solutions, plus one.

I had the idea to start from the end of the list and move down in a descending order.

This is my code so far:

```
piles=[11, 26, 37, 44, 49, 52, 68, 75,87, 102]
p=piles
n=len(piles)
moves=0
while sum(piles)>0:
    for i in range(len(piles)-1,0,-1):
        if piles[i-1]<piles[i]:
            piles[i]=piles[i]-piles[i-1]
            if piles[i] in p:
                piles.remove(piles[i])
                moves+=1
```

Comment: Please could you be more specific than `reduce all elements in the array to 0` - what logic are you using to reduce an element to 0

Comment: @TheThonnu, `102-87-75+68-52+44`

Comment: @TheThonnu, better to wait for answer from author. That was just my guess

Comment: if a previous element is less than the current element that element can reduce it until eventually all elements in a list become 0

Comment: Is multiplication/division also allowed? If so, is it only the last element being multiplicated/divided or the whole result already gained? You should definately specify more what you mean with 'moves', in your question and with full sentences instead of xamples.

Comment: @ralph_c, could you work out an example? I can't understand what you mean by previous and current element. Is current the element with index `i` and previous the one with index `i-1`? Also, what do you mean by all elements in a list become 0, but you have a number of moves. What does a move mean? Subtracting two elements?

Comment: By `that element can reduce it` do you mean something like 37 gets reduced by 26 and 11 so that's 0

Comment: how many minimum operations will it take to reduce each element to 0. After you reduce one element by another so say 102-87=15 you need to find other elements in the list that will reduce 15. the differences will keep updating for each element however.

Comment: Can you provide a worked out example, in a list with maybe 4 elements? Also, what to do with lists that cannot be reduced (for example, `[1, 2]`). Finally, are all lists sorted? Is the order important?

Comment: the list is sorted. i gave an example on top. basically the optimal moves for list=[2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89] would be [55, 21, 8, 3, 2] and this 5 moves taken to reduce the original list to 0

Comment: @raphc, you have not answered simple questions yet. What operations allowed? How to deal with list that can't be "reduced"?

Comment: If I subtract all the numbers you gave from 89, that indeed gets to 0, so 5 moves for 89. For 55, I can subtract 34 and 21. In your fist example you can follow this pattern until you get to 26, that cannot be summed/subtract with 11 to get 0. Is it a rule that you can only use as moves elements that are smaller than the current one? Are negative elements allowed?

Comment: Is this a variation of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)? Particularly one in which each element of the list becomes the goal and the subset in question is based on the other numbers in the list (eventually extending it by multiplying all by -1).

Comment: Each move chooses one of the remaining
pile sizes p, and removes p cookies from every pile that contains at least p cookies (thus eradicating
all piles with exactly p cookies), and leaves all smaller piles untouched as they were

Comment: This
function should return the smallest number of moves that allows Cookie Monster to scarf down
these cookies. For the given piles, your function should loop trough its possible moves, and
recursively solve the problem for the new piles that result from applying each move to piles. The
optimal solution for piles is then simply the optimal one of those subproblem solutions, plus one.

Comment: its called the cookie monster problem

Comment: @ralph_c, please update the question with the description you gave in the previous comments (including saying it is the cookie monster problem). Everybody else was understanding something completely different. You'll try to work out a solution.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an [A* algorithm with an "admissible" heurstic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

When we have a list of  distinct values, we can at best hope to take a pile, such that the other piles from which that amount is subtracted, now all match with another pile from which no subtraction took place. That means that at most we can reduce the number of piles with the selected pile and half of the others, so  becomes (-1)/2

So we will need at least 1+floor(log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub>) moves to reach the goal. We can see an instance of this minimum in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. The optimal solution for this particular input always takes the middle value, so that we halve the list with each move:

- take 4, result => [1,2,3,1,2,3] => [1,2,3]
- take 2, result => [1, 1] => [1]
- take 1, done.

Here is an implementation of a A* algorithm with that heuristic, and with marking configurations as "visited", to avoid solving the same pile-configuration twice:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

def food(piles):
    if not piles:
        return 0
    node = frozenset(piles)
    heap = [(len(node).bit_length(), 0, node, [])]
    visited = set()

    while heap:
        heuristic, cost, node, moves = heappop(heap)
        if len(node) == 1:
            return moves + [min(node)]
        if len(node) == 2:
            return moves + [min(node), max(node) - min(node)]
        cost += 1
        for amount in node:
            neighbor = frozenset(pile - amount if pile > amount else pile
                                 for pile in node if pile != amount)
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor)
                heappush(heap, (cost + len(neighbor).bit_length(), cost, neighbor, 
                                moves + [amount]))
```

This code returns the list of moves to perform. If it is only needed to return the minimal *number* of moves, then the above can be simplified to:

```
def food(piles):
    if not piles:
        return 0
    node = frozenset(piles)
    heap = [(len(node).bit_length(), 0, node)]
    visited = set()

    while heap:
        heuristic, cost, node = heappop(heap)
        if len(node) <= 2:
            return heuristic
        cost += 1
        for amount in node:
            neighbor = frozenset(pile - amount if pile > amount else pile
                                 for pile in node if pile != amount)
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor)
                heappush(heap, (cost + len(neighbor).bit_length(), cost, neighbor))
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer, as the solution is clearly more efficient.

Comment: Voted up. Note that there can be multiple answers. For the example with 102, [3, 4, 7, 15, 34, 68] is also a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

The proposal below does a brute force search, using as possible moves the size of each cookie pile (I'm not sure this ensures that this ensures optimality, as in principle a number not in the pile could be optimal). Also, since a brute force is done, in the worst case a factorial number of cases will be tried, so for inputs larger than 10 or 11 the execution time (and memory) may become unmanageable (but I'll show how to improve on that later).

The recursion depth is the length of the input - 2, so quite shallow. The algorithm is pretty simple: at any step, for all possible moves, it selects a move and then solve the sub-problem after that move is made. Since every movie eats at least one pile, the number of piles is always smaller at every step. It selects the shortest solution out of all possible ones. We could have done a slight optimisation here in that, since we know the smallest possible size of a solution, if we found a solution with this size we stop searching for more, since we cannot do better than the current one anyway.

An additional optimisation that was not done is that the question requests the **length** of the smallest solution, and the code below produces a sequence of moves that is (hopefully) minimal.

```py
def solve_cookie_monster_problem(piles):
    if len(piles) <= 2:  # This is the end of recursion condition. 2 jars always need two moves
        return list(piles)

    # Try each element in piles as a move, and return the solution with the least moves
    best_try = range(len(piles) + 1)  # This is longer than any try
    for move in piles:
        next_piles = {(el - move) if el > move else el
                      for el in piles if el != move}
        current_try = solve_cookie_monster_problem(next_piles)
        current_try.append(move)
        if len(current_try) < len(best_try):
            best_try = current_try
    # best_try contains the shortest solution
    return best_try
```

The result is quite slow on my machine (all tests cases below run in about 5 s). There is a simple way to improve **significantly** this algorithm, if we note that each recursion step might visit problems that were already solved before: we can memoise the function, i.e. record previous results and simply return then, if we see a call with the same configuration of cookies. This is extremely simple to implement with python dictionaries. This simple improvement reduced the execution time from 5s to about 0.25s in the test cases below.

```py
def solve_cookie_monster_memoised(initial_piles):
    """Memoised version of solve_cookie_monster.
    Essentially the same algorithm, but checking if that particular sub-problem hasn't been solved before."""

    memory = {}  # Will record subproblems already solved
    def get(value): return list(memory[value])  # Always create a copy when accessing the memoised
    initial_piles = frozenset(initial_piles)

    def algorithm(piles):
        if piles in memory:
            return get(piles)

        if len(piles) <= 2:  # This is the end of recursion condition. 2 jars always need two moves
            memory[piles] = list(piles)
            return get(piles)

        # Try each element in piles as a move, and return the solution with the least moves
        best_try = range(len(piles) + 1)  # This is longer than any try
        for move in piles:
            next_piles = frozenset({(el - move) if el > move else el
                                    for el in piles if el != move})
            current_try = algorithm(next_piles)
            current_try.append(move)
            if len(current_try) < len(best_try):
                best_try = current_try
        memory[piles] = best_try
        return get(piles)
    return algorithm(initial_piles)
```

Here are some test cases:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    piles1 = [2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
    piles2 = [11, 26, 37, 44, 49, 52, 68, 75, 87, 102]
    piles3 = [7, 4, 3, 1]
    piles4 = [20, 19, 14, 7, 4]
    piles5 = [18, 16, 9, 8]
    piles6 = [11, 26, 37, 44, 49, 52, 68, 75, 87, 89, 102]

    tstart = time.perf_counter()
    print(solve_cookie_monster_problem(piles1))  # [2, 3, 8, 21, 55]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_problem(piles2))  # [3, 4, 7, 15, 34, 68]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_problem(piles3))  # [1, 4, 3]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_problem(piles4))  # [1, 2, 4, 14]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_problem(piles5))  # [1, 2, 8, 16]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_problem(piles6))  # [1, 3, 7, 16, 37, 49]
    tend = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Time: {tend-tstart:.2f}')  # About 5s on my machine

    print('\nMemoised version')
    tstart = time.perf_counter()
    print(solve_cookie_monster_memoised(piles1))  # [2, 3, 8, 21, 55]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_memoised(piles2))  # [3, 4, 7, 15, 34, 68]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_memoised(piles3))  # [1, 4, 3]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_memoised(piles4))  # [1, 2, 4, 14]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_memoised(piles5))  # [1, 2, 8, 16]
    print(solve_cookie_monster_memoised(piles6))  # [1, 3, 7, 16, 37, 49]
    tend = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Time: {tend-tstart:.2f}')  # About 0.25s on my machine
```

A modification of this code to return only the length is trivial, and will improve a bit the performance (about 10% in the non-memoised version).